# How to export .csv file with merge cells into mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

In my .csv file there is a data like this : 
id | code | name
1mca | 3ca1523 | c
     | 3ca1524 | cpp
     | 3ca1525 | java
3mca | 3ca1621 | php
     | 3ca1624 | ooad

my code to export this into mysql :

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("could not connect");

if(!$db)

die("no db");

if(!mysqli_select_db($db,"phptester"))

die("No database selected.");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo $uploadfile;


if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)) 
{

$handle = fopen("$uploadfile", "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)
{

$import="INSERT into subject(sem,code,name) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]')";
mysqli_query($db,$import) or die(mysql_error());
}
fclose($handle);
print "Import done";
}
}
else
{
print "<form action='index.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
print "Choose file to import:<br><br>";
print "<input type='file' name='file' id='file'><br><br>";
print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='extract'></form>";
}
?>
```

So, there is a merged column in a csv file, when i run this script first record is inserted like this 1mca,3ca1524,c and next record like this   ,3ca1525,cpp instead i want in the second record there should be 1mca inserted in the first field how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

on line where is:

`while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE)`

try to replace for:

`while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "|")) !== FALSE)`

Third parameter of **fgetcsv** is delimiter  for fetching data from csv. you have "**,**" instead of "**|**"